# How to add another dbs to car

Tags: wso2, pom.xml, wso2-data-services-server

I have the following plugin which builds a car containing a dbs service named ABC.dbs:

```
<groupId>some group</groupId>
<artifactId>some-dss</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
<packaging>service/dataservice</packaging> 
<name>some-dss</name>
<description>some-dss</description>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dataservice-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <artifact>src/main/dataservice/ABC.dbs</artifact>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
      <buildcommands />
      <projectnatures>
        <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.ds.project.nature</projectnature>
      </projectnatures>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I have another dbs now.  How do I configure this plugin to add another dbs?  I tried:

```
    <configuration>
      <artifact>src/main/dataservice/ABC.dbs</artifact>
      <artifact>src/main/dataservice/DEF.dbs</artifact>
    </configuration>
```

but the car only has DEF.dbs.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**The feature is available in Developer studio 3.8.0**

with maven plugin - **maven-dataservice-plugin - version : 2.1.0**

**Reference:**

http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/

http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Multiple-dbs-files-support-in-a-single-Data-Services-Project-via-Developer-Studio-td115686.html